# Google map for flex deprecated

Tags: google-maps

I've read that from September 2, 2014, google MAP API for Flash will no longer be available.
How will it affect my application?
It will no longer show the map at all or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calls made to the Flash API will fail. This means that your application won't be able to authenticate, download tiles or satellite imagery. If there's content on cache you can expect your application to behave unexpectedly and be really glitchy.